# How long can Sonic stay underwater?

Tags: sonic-mania

If Sonic stays underwater for too long without surfacing or finding an air bubble, "danger" music will start playing alongside a countdown leading to Sonic running out of air and dying.

[According to an IGN guide](http://www.ign.com/faqs/2003/sonic-classics-3-in-1-sonic-compilation-general-faq-424263), Sonic could stay underwater for 30 seconds in Sonic 2, but I'm unsure whether this applies to Sonic Mania. (Or any other Sonic games for that matter)

**How long can Sonic stay underwater before running out of air?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I timed it in my game, and it appears to also be 30 seconds.

I started a stop watch on my phone the second I jumped in, and got 29.90 seconds when I died.  The .1 of a second is almost certainly just due to my timing.  The countdown bubbles next to Sonic's head go down at a rate of about 2 seconds each from the looks of it.  So, once you see those, you have about 10 seconds to get some air.

Comment: If it's the same as Sonic 2, then this quote from the IGN guide likely still applies. "*30 seconds. It takes 5 seconds for the first "ding" warning, and the warning repeats at 10 seconds and 15 seconds. After 18 seconds (or 3 seconds after the 3rd warning), the "danger" music and countdown start. The countdown lasts 12 seconds.*"

Comment: Feel free to edit the quote into your answer if you'd like. Marking this answer as accepted.